# Android: Cursor is always returning null even if the database is not empty

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

Cursor is always returning null even if the database is not empty. Why? and how to solve that? Thank you.

```
 public StatParcours getOneUserInfo(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, new String[] { KEY_USER_ID,
            KEY_STUDN , KEY_STUDBD, KEY_TEACHN, KEY_TEACHBD}, KEY_USER_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

    StatParcours stat = null;
    if ((cursor!= null)&&(cursor.moveToFirst())){      
        stat = new StatParcours(
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), 
            cursor.getString(2),
            cursor.getString(3),
            cursor.getString(4));
    }  
    return stat ;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the cursor is null? Perhaps it just doesn't have any rows? Have you checked that the query you are making will return at least 1 result?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the database content using Log, than displayed value of Stat when I call this method, witch is always null. So  understood that cursor always null.

Comment: If you do `Log.d("Foo", "Cursor is:" + cursor);` does that print `Cursor is: null`? If that does not print `null` then cursor is empty. Empty means your query has found 0 elements that match the criteria and you may need to check if your query is wrong.

Comment: Its printing: **Cursor is:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@428085b0**

Comment: You do not need to check for null just moveToFirst() is enough. If the cursor is empty moveToFirst() will return false.

Comment: Tried that with no results.

Comment: Just put a log inside the moveToFirst() block. Log.d("Foo", "cursor is not empty") to see if it shows in logcat. If not then the cursor is empty.

Comment: like I have already mentioned in he previous comment , the logcat (placed just before the if blck  is showing: *Cursor is:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@428085b0*
I have inserted another one inside the if, but as it's not getting inside, it shows nothing

Comment: So your cursor is not null, it is empty. That means that there is nothing in your database that matches `KEY_USER_ID + "=?"`. Check the value of `id` and you should see that there is nothing with exactly that value.

Comment: The cursor is never null so your log shows as above. If you do not get anything inside the if block that means the cursor is empty. Check if you get the right id.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the user ID against a string value, which will never succeed if your user IDs are numbers.

In Android, you should use query parameters only for string values; you should embed integers directly into the query string:

```
cursor = db.query(..., ..., KEY_USER_ID + "=" + id, null, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should enture the cursor is null or not and if not, you need confirm the cursor.getCount() is not zero, are you sure?

```
if (cursor!= null && cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst()){
    //do something
}
```

if cursor is null or cursor.getCount() is zero, but database exist and data is correct, you should detect your sql  and run command in terminal or sql client to fix this issue.

Comment: Checking for `null` is not necessary, and the `getCount` and `moveToFirst` checks are redundant.

Comment: people keep saying checking for cursor==null is not necessary, the reason is that the case where cursor *is* null, `query` will have thrown an exception, so you won't get to the check.

Answer (score 0):

The CursorFactory value when create the database should be null if you don't have specific requirement.

That's how I solved this problem.